# how to make more than condition in toString method

Tags: java

I want to list all names that end with "Reda" and ignore case sensitivity, I have tried the condition in the `toString` method at the bottom, but it would not print any thing.

```
public class Customer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File a = new File("customer.txt");
        FileWriter v = new FileWriter(a);
        BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(v);
        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(b);

        human Iman = new human("Iman", 5000);
        human Nour = new human("Nour", 3500);
        human Redah = new human("Redah", 0);
        human iman = new human("iman", 200);
        human MohamedREDA = new human("MohamedREDA", 3000);
        human Mohamed_Redah = new human("Mohamed Redah", 2000);

        human[] h = new human[6];

        h[0] = Iman;
        h[1] = Nour;
        h[2] = Redah;
        h[3] = iman;
        h[4] = MohamedREDA;
        h[5] = Mohamed_Redah;

        p.println(Iman);
        p.println(Nour);
        p.println(Redah);
        p.println(iman);
        p.println(MohamedREDA);
        p.println(Mohamed_Redah);

        p.flush();
    }

}

class human {
    public String name;
    public double balance;

    public human(String n, double b) {
        this.balance = b;
        this.name = n;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Reda") && (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Reda"))) {
            return name + " " + balance;
        } else
            return " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: this.name.toLowerCase().endsWith(str.toLowerCase())

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid putting condition in `toString` method. Remove the condition there

```
public String toString() {
    return name + " " + balance;
}
```

and change your logic in `Customer` class

```
human[] h = new human[6];

h[0] = Iman;
h[1] = Nour;
h[2] = Redah;
h[3] = iman;
h[4] = MohamedREDA;
h[5] = Mohamed_Redah;

for (int i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
    if (h[i].name.toLowerCase().endsWith("reda")) { // condition here
        p.println(h[i]);
    }
}
```

And make use of `loops` do not duplicate the lines of code.Every where you are manually writing the lines.

Check [Java String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and use required methods to add condition.

Comment: but array h is declared in different class so i can not use it in current class

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put such condition in `toString()` method cause, it's not properly put business application logic in this method.

> `toString()` is the string representation of an object.

What you can do, is putting the condition before calling the `toString()` , or making a `helper` method for this.

```
private boolean endsWithIgnoringCase(String other){
 return this.name.toLowerCase().endsWith(other.toLowerCase()); 
}
```

Comment: @Baadshah im not english native speaker, but im saying that putting such a condition in `toString()` you are breaking the contract

Answer (score 0):

```
String redahname = ("Redah").toLowerCase();   //put your h[0] instead of ("Redah")

        if(name.endsWith("redah")){ //IMPORTANT TO BE IN LOWER CASE, (it is case insenitive this way)
            //your code here if it ends with redag
            System.out.println(redahname);
        } //if it does not end with "redah" it wont out print it!
```

You can use this, but can you please explain your question more? What exactly do you need?

Comment: i need the output like  Mohamedreda 3000  all names that end with "Reda". with Ignore case sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   @Override
    public String toString() {

        if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith("reda"))) {
            return name + " " + balance;
        } else
            return " ";
    }
```

Comment: i doubt that any one of us have understood your question properly, can you please elaborate on the output required

Comment: also i couldnt find any using of `h` humar array in your code

Comment: it's not good putting business logic in the `toString`, you are saying that all string representation of `customer` or whatever are " " if they don't endsWith reda ..

Comment: I do know that, I just wanted to help the user in achieving wat he/she wants

Answer (score 0):

1. None of your `human`s are called, ignoring case, `Reda`, so your observation of no names printed is the manifestation of properly working logic.
2. Your condition is redundant: you perform the same test twice:

   ```
   name.equalsIgnoreCase("Reda") && (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Reda"))
   ```
3. If you need to match only the string ending, you should employ a regular expression:

   ```
   name.matches("(?i).*reda")
   ```
4. `toString` is a general-purpose method defined for all objects. Using it the way you do, baking in the business logic for just one special use case, cannot be correct. You must rewrite the code so that `toString` uniformly returns a string representation of the object.

Comment: Marko a question? why using regex instead of endsWith?

Comment: `ebdsWith` is case-sensitive and `toLowerCase` creates an unnecessary copy. Here that may not matter, but I prefer a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

`String.equals()` is not what you want as you're looking for strings which *ends with* "Reda" instead of those equal to "Reda".  Using `String.match` or `String.endsWith` together with `String.toLowerCase` will do this for you.  The following is the example of `String.match`:

```
public class Reda {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names = {"Iman", "MohamedREDA", "Mohamed Redah", "reda"};

    for (String name : names) {
      // the input to matches is a regular expression.
      // . stands for any character, * stands for may repeating any times
      // [Rr] stands for either R or r.
      if (name.matches(".*[Rr][Ee][Dd][Aa]")) {
        System.out.println(name);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and its output:

```
MohamedREDA
reda
```

and here is the solution using `endsWith` and `toLowerCase`:

```
public class Reda {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names = {"Iman", "MohamedREDA", "Mohamed Redah", "reda"};

    for (String name : names) {
      if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith("reda")) {
        System.out.println(name);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and its output:

```
MohamedREDA
reda
```